# form with images in background when top one is high

Tags: css

I have form with background consisting of 4 parts: frame_border_top.png (height 18px), form_border_top.png (height 200px, there is gradient on this picture), frame_border_middle (height: 1px, repeat-y) and frame_border_bottom.png (18px). And I need to build form background from those images. The difficulty is that form content should begin display na form_border_top.png (it shoukd be background for top 5 or 6 inputs). So the form should be (top to bottom, pixel are on Y axis):
0-17px frame_border_top.png
18px-217px form_border_top.png
218px-599px (or whateveor, depending on content height) frame_border_middle
600px-617px frame_border_bottom

And text starting at 20px.

How to style this with css? It would be easy but this form_border_top.png part.

And it must work in IE7.

I tried such HTML

```
    <div id="Content">
        <form action="">
            <div class="form-top"></div>
            <div class="form-background-top"></div>
            <div class="form-content">
                ... inputs ...
            </div>
            <div class="form-bottom"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and

```
#Content {
    width: 942px;
}

form {
}

.form-top {
    background: url("images/form_top.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 18px;
}
.form-background-top {
    background: url("images/form_background.png") no-repeat 
        scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 200px;
}
.form-content {
    background: url("images/form_middle.png") repeat-y 
        scroll center 0 transparent;
}
.form-bottom {
    background: url("images/form_bottom.png") repeat 
        scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 18px;
}
```

and tried different combinations of position, margin, padding but without success.

Comment: So you want to add border images *in addition to* the background-images already on those `<div>`s? So `.form-top` which has background image of form_top.png should have border of form_border_top.png?

Comment: Yes. But then I will have to modify png but that may be best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified pngs. I created outer layer only with borders and transparent inside. Then I created png for gradient background but without border. Then it was easy to put all together.